# Put text in whitespace wrapfigure of subfloats

Tags: floats, subfloats, wrapfigure, wrap, white-space

I've got this right now:
[image]

As you can see, the text does not occupy the whitespace above the left graph which makes it look very awkward.

It also has to work with multiple lines\sections\paragraphs etc.

I would like that space to be usable with by the text. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{10cm}
    \begin{center}
    \subfloat[Example one]{
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{a}{Test}
            \newthread{b}{Test}

            \begin{sdblock}{Test}{}
                \mess{a}{Test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sequencediagram}
    }
    \subfloat[Example number two with a long caption.]{
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{a}{Testing}
            \newthread{b}{Very much testing}

            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}

            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}

            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sequencediagram}
    }
    \caption{My mice graphs.}   
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Edit:
specifying the height of the wrapfigure gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try specifying the height of the wrapfigure (optional argument).

Comment: Did that, edited

Comment: if I run the example as posted I get output not like either image you show, all the text on all three pages is in one narrow column t the left of the image

Comment: That shouldn't be possible with LaTeX right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shape the paragraphs, which requires a bit of hand work, but less than involved in producing the tikz layout so perhaps an acceptable solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}



\def\sln{0pt .4\textwidth}
\def\mln{0pt .65\textwidth}
\def\lln{0pt \textwidth}


\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(170,0){%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \subfloat[Example one]{
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{a}{Test}
            \newthread{b}{Test}
            \begin{sdblock}{Test}{}
                \mess{a}{Test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sequencediagram}
    }
    \subfloat[Example number two with a long caption.]{
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            \newthread{a}{Testing}
            \newthread{b}{Very much testing}
%
            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
%
            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
%
            \begin{sdblock}{Event}{}
                \mess{a}{Long test}{b}
            \end{sdblock}
        \end{sequencediagram}
    }
    \caption{My mice graphs.}   
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{picture}

\parshape 12
\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln\mln
\sln
\lipsum[1]

\parshape 1
\sln
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. But it's a shame there's so much hardcoding. I had to hardcode every `\section`'s paragraph lengths again