# how to fill up white spaces in wrapfigure with subfigures

Tags: wrapfigure, white-space, subfig

I have the following page where I want to fill up the white space (red drawings) with the paragraph.
[image]

There is already a post and solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459672/put-text-in-whitespace-wrapfigure-of-subfloats): which is very cumbersome where I may have to change all the paragraph lengths of all subsections as one of the comments mentions there. Are there any smart easier way to achieve what I need?

I will try to post my MWE:

```
        \usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
        \graphicspath{ {./figures/} } % folder where the images or figures are
        \usepackage{subcaption}
        \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % make Figure 1 bold
        \usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping a figure with words
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \begin{document}
        ....
        \subsubsection{demo subsection}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.8\textwidth}
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                \centering\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/universe.jpg}
                    \subcaption{}
                    \label{fig:5a}\par\vfill
                \end{subfigure}
                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/meanspecclusters.png}
                    \subcaption{}
                    \label{fig:5b}
                \end{subfigure}
            \end{minipage}
        \caption{Figure}\label{fig:5}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \lipsum[2]
        ....
        \end{document}
```

Comment: The minipuge in unneeded, and {h!) is not a wrapfigure option

Comment: @JohnKormylo sorry I didn't use h!, it must be got copied somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you could do this with two wrapfigures, one after the other, but you would still have to break the paragraph manually between the two.  If you are going to break paragraphs manually, you might as well use paracol (much more robust).

The basic idea is to leave a blank space into which one can overlap the larger image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
%\graphicspath{ {./figures/} } % folder where the images or figures are
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % make Figure 1 bold
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}

\begin{document}
        \subsubsection{demo subsection}
        \lipsum[1]
        \savebox{\tempboxa}{\includegraphics[width=0.36\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}}% measure height
        \savebox{\tempboxb}{\includegraphics[width=0.36\textwidth]{example-image}}% measure height
        \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.64\textwidth-\columnsep}
        \begin{paracol}{2}
        \sloppy
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales,
sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non
justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor
sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet
magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut
massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturi ent
\splitpar[\dimexpr 0.28\textwidth-2\columnsep]{%
montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum
turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.}
        \switchcolumn
        \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\tempboxa-\ht\tempboxb}% empty space
        %\hrule% show bottom of empty space
        \end{paracol}
        \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.28\textwidth-2\columnsep}
        \begin{paracol}{2}
        \continuepar
        \switchcolumn
        \begin{figure}[h]
          \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
                \begin{subfigure}{\wd\tempboxb}
                    \usebox\tempboxb
                    \caption{}
                    \label{fig:5a}
                \end{subfigure}\hfill
                \begin{subfigure}{\wd\tempboxa}
                    \raisebox{0pt}[\ht\tempboxb]{\usebox\tempboxa}
                    \subcaption{}
                    \label{fig:5b}
                \end{subfigure}
          \caption{Figure}\label{fig:5}
        \end{figure}
        \switchcolumn
        \sloppy
Nulla malesuada
porttitor diam. Donec
felis erat, congue
\splitpar{non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique,
libero. Vivamus
viverra fermentum
felis. Donec
nonummy pellentesque
ante. Phasellus
adipiscing semper
elit. Proin fermentum
massa ac
quam. Sed diam
turpis, molestie vitae,
placerat a, molestie
nec, leo. Maecenas
lacinia. Nam
ipsum ligula, eleifend
at, accumsan
nec, suscipit a, ipsum.
Morbi blandit
ligula feugiat magna.
Nunc eleifend
consequat lorem.
Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim.
Pellentesque tincidunt
purus vel magna.
Integer non
enim. Praesent euismod
nunc eu purus.
Donec bibendum
quam in tellus.
Nullam cursus pulvinar
lectus. Donec
et mi. Nam
vulputate metus eu
enim. Vestibulum
pellentesque felis eu
massa.}
        \end{paracol}
        \continuepar
\end{document}
```