# Two different footnote styles within the same document

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, revtex

I'm using RevTeX 4.2, and my document is made of a "main text" (formatted on 2 columns) and a "Supplemental Material" (formatted on 1 column, to which I switch using \onecolumngrid), appearing after the bibliography.

I'd like the footnotes of the main text to appear as entries in the bibliography, but at the same time I'd like the footnotes of the Supplemental Material to appear as actual footnotes at the bottom of the current page (indeed, it makes no sense that they come before the text they refer to).

I am aware of the option `nofootinbib`, but this is set once and for all for the whole document, while I would like to switch from one option to the other within the document.

Comment: If the supplemental material fits on one page, you can use a minipage.  Otherwise, check out the manyfoot package.  If this is for publication, get permission first.

Comment: @JohnKormylo unfortunately it does not fit in a single page. Besides, both `manyfoot` and `bigfoot` seem to be incompatible with my RevTex document: they generate a lot of compilation errors as soon as I include them in my preamble...

Comment: Considering the difficulty of modifying \output to handle more than one \footins, it would be eaiser to manually break the material over multiple minipages.  See \splitpar and \continuepar from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659159/how-to-fill-up-white-spaces-in-wrapfigure-with-subfigures/659169?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#659169

Comment: Looking over the revtex4-2 code, the bibnotes and nobibnotes options are easy to implement (it's even in the manual, albeit chopped off).  The \frontmatter prefix worries me.  Needs experimentation.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `bibnotes` has the same problem as `nofootinbib`, i.e. it must be set once and for all for the whole document. It also seems to concern author data, and not footnotes in general.

Comment: Depending on how it is implemented, you might be able to switch it on and off. 
\frontmatter@footnote@produce@footnote is short and \frontmatter@footnote@produce@endnote does nothing.  OTOH, the whole process is rather obscure.