Picture inside the proof environment
While compiling the code below, I wasn't able to place the picture inside the proof environment. I am wondering how to fix this. Thank you!
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{covering unit circle by smaller circle}
If $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then we can cover the unit circle $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with at most $\lceil \frac{\pi}{r}\rceil$ circles of radius $r$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [color=black] (-2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [color=black] (-0.13,0.8) circle (0.8cm);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(0,0);%
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.17,0.8);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0)--(-0.17,0.8); %line AB
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.6,1.45); %line OC
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-0.17,0.8)--(-0.615,1.44); %line CB
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2,0) circle (0.7pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.1,-0.1) node {$O$};
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.7pt); %point A
\draw[color=black] (0.1,-0.15) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.615,1.44) circle (0.7pt);%point C
\draw[color=black] (-0.6,1.6) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.17,0.8) circle (0.7pt); %dot B
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node {$B$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1em} % Optional: add some vertical space after the picture

Consider the unit circle centered at $O$ of radius $|OA|=1$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thanks for the remark! Done.

Quick hack: place something else, e.g. an empty \mbox in the line after the \paragraph{} so that the tikzpicture can go to the next line
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{covering unit circle by smaller circle}
If $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then we can cover the unit circle $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with at most $\lceil \frac{\pi}{r}\rceil$ circles of radius $r$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}\mbox{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4,line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [color=black] (-2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [color=black] (-0.13,0.8) circle (0.8cm);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(0,0);%
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.17,0.8);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0)--(-0.17,0.8); %line AB
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.6,1.45); %line OC
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-0.17,0.8)--(-0.615,1.44); %line CB
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2,0) circle (0.7pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.1,-0.1) node {$O$};
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.7pt); %point A
\draw[color=black] (0.1,-0.15) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.615,1.44) circle (0.7pt);%point C
\draw[color=black] (-0.6,1.6) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.17,0.8) circle (0.7pt); %dot B
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node {$B$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\vspace{1em} % Optional: add some vertical space after the picture

Consider the unit circle centered at $O$ of radius $|OA|=1$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}



Thanks! Also I am wondering how to remove some space around the picture because you see that there is a gap between "Proof" and the picture.

@RFZ The tremendous amount of white space is not around the picture, it is part of the picture. You'll see it if you replace the line starting with \clip with \draw(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);. If you don't want all this space, don't add it in the picture.

I warmly suggest to load amsthm for the proof environment. Your definition isn't guaranteed to place the QED symbol at the end of a line.
Remove the GeoGebra \clip instruction: it always adds it, I can't understand why.
I'd also suggest to center the picture, which also solves the formatting problem. Reducing the scale is definitely better, in my opinion.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{covering unit circle by smaller circle}
If $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then we can cover the unit 
circle $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with at most 
$\lceil \frac{\pi}{r}\rceil$ circles of radius $r$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  %scale=1.5,
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  %>=triangle 45,
  %x=1.0cm,
  %y=1.0cm
]
%\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [color=black] (-2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [color=black] (-0.13,0.8) circle (0.8cm);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(0,0);%
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.17,0.8);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0)--(-0.17,0.8); %line AB
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.6,1.45); %line OC
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-0.17,0.8)--(-0.615,1.44); %line CB
%\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2,0) circle (0.7pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.1,-0.1) node {\scriptsize$O$};
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.7pt); %point A
\draw[color=black] (0.1,-0.15) node {\scriptsize$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.615,1.44) circle (0.7pt);%point C
\draw[color=black] (-0.6,1.6) node {\scriptsize$C$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.17,0.8) circle (0.7pt); %dot B
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node {\scriptsize$B$};
%\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
Consider the unit circle centered at $O$ of radius $|OA|=1$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}


With a different format:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{covering unit circle by smaller circle}
If $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then we can cover the unit 
circle $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with at most 
$\lceil \frac{\pi}{r}\rceil$ circles of radius $r$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Consider the unit circle centered at $O$ of radius $|OA|=1$.
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  baseline=(current bounding box.south),
  %scale=1.5,
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  %>=triangle 45,
  %x=1.0cm,
  %y=1.0cm
]
%\clip(-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw [color=black] (-2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [color=black] (-0.13,0.8) circle (0.8cm);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(0,0);%
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.17,0.8);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0)--(-0.17,0.8); %line AB
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.6,1.45); %line OC
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-0.17,0.8)--(-0.615,1.44); %line CB
%\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=black] (-2,0) circle (0.7pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.1,-0.1) node {\scriptsize$O$};
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.7pt); %point A
\draw[color=black] (0.1,-0.15) node {\scriptsize$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.615,1.44) circle (0.7pt);%point C
\draw[color=black] (-0.6,1.6) node {\scriptsize$C$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.17,0.8) circle (0.7pt); %dot B
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node {\scriptsize$B$};
%\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\end{document}



This uses paracol to place the proof and image side by side.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{paracol}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{covering unit circle by smaller circle}
If $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$, then we can cover the unit circle $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with at most $\lceil \frac{\pi}{r}\rceil$ circles of radius $r$.
\end{lemma}
\savebox{\tempbox}{% measure width
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4,line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=black] (-2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [color=black] (-0.13,0.8) circle (0.8cm);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(0,0);%
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.17,0.8);
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (0,0)--(-0.17,0.8); %line AB
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-2,0)--(-0.6,1.45); %line OC
\draw [line width=0.4pt] (-0.17,0.8)--(-0.615,1.44); %line CB
\begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
\fill [color=black] (-2,0) circle (0.7pt);
\draw[color=black] (-2.1,-0.1) node {$O$};
\fill [color=black] (0,0) circle (0.7pt); %point A
\draw[color=black] (0.1,-0.15) node {$A$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.615,1.44) circle (0.7pt);%point C
\draw[color=black] (-0.6,1.6) node {$C$};
\fill [color=black] (-0.17,0.8) circle (0.7pt); %dot B
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node {$B$};
\end{scope}
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%\vspace{1em} % Optional: add some vertical space after the picture
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}% second column gets \wd\tempbox
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{proof}
Consider the unit circle centered at $O$ of radius $|OA|=1$.
\end{proof}
\switchcolumn
\noindent\usebox\tempbox
\end{paracol}

\end{document}



I am a bit confused. The content of the proof section is actually larger, but when I paste it, the space under the picture remains empty. I am wondering how to fix this issue.

paracol doesn't wrap the text around the picture.  Wrapfig is used for that, but it has other problems.  In this case, the text didn't stretch far enough..  I use \splitpar and \continuepar to manually end the paracol in the middle of a paragrah ( see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659159/how-to-fill-up-white-spaces-in-wrapfigure-with-subfigures for example).
